# How to make my next button to submit form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I am creating a student information form in html as in the image:

[image]

My next button is an image and the code for it is as follows:

```
<input type="image" id="registersubmit6" name="registersubmit6" src="images/arrow-right.png"  title="finish" onclick=""/>
```

When user clicks on next button, I want to submit this form and move to next page.How I can do both at the moment?

Should I use javascript or PHP? and if yes then how?

Comment: onclick event trigger form.submit() assuming you are wrapping the text fields in a form.

Comment: You just have to include this button inside your `form`

Comment: @sabithpocker that is not a button, that is image.. `<input type="image"..`

Comment: @Mr_Green OP mentioned "when user clicks on next button" so for sake of communication. Its an input element which can act as submit, but without ability to take values with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="image" id="registersubmit6" name="registersubmit6" src="images/arrow-right.png"  title="finish" onclick="submitForm()"/>
function submitForm(){
document.getElementById('id of your form').submit();
}
```

Comment: thanks...but when next button is pressed, I want to submit the form and move to next step. then how i can do?

Comment: can you explain what is "next step"? moving to another page?

Comment: 'next step' is moving to the page which contains another form of 'step 3'.

Comment: add this after calling `submit()`: `window.location.href='url to your step3 form page';`